# Question about occupation time of a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Theorem:  Let $D=B(0,r)=\{y:|y|<r\}$. $B_t$ will return to $D$ i.o. in $d\leq 2$ in a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion. Then for any $x$

$$
\begin{align}
P_x \left( \int_0^{\infty} 1_D(B_t)dt = \infty \right) &= 1 \text{ for $d\leq 2$
} \\
\end{align}
$$

> I have a couple of questions about the proof

Proof: Let $T_0 = 0$ and $G = B(0,2r)$. For $k\geq 1$, let

$$
\begin{align}
S_k &= \inf\{t> T_{k-1}:B_t\in D\} \\
T_k &= \inf\{t> S_{k}:B_t\in G\} \\
\end{align}
$$

Writing $\tau$ for $T_1$ and using the strong Markov property, we get for $k\geq 1$:

$$P_x\left( \int_{S_k}^{T_k}1_D(B_t)dt\geq s\Bigg|\mathcal{F}_{S_k}\right) = P_{B(S_k)}\left( \int_0^{\tau}1_D(B_t)dt \geq s \right)$$

From the strong Markov property it follows that

$$\int_{S_k}^{T_k}1_D(B_t)dt \;\;\;\;\text{ are i.i.d.}$$

Since these random variables have positive mean, it follows from the strong law that:

$$\int_0^\infty 1_D(B_t)dt\geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{S_k}^{T_k}1_D(B_t)dt = \infty \;\;\text{ a.s.}$$

> 1) From the definition of $T_k$, isn't $T_k = 0$ a.s.? If we start from a point in $D$, any Brownian path that hits $G$ has to go through $G$? I am confused about this.
>
> 2) Why are $\int_{S_k}^{T_k}1_D(B_t)dt$ identically distributed? If we start from a point in $D$, why doesn't the probability distribution of $\int_{S_k}^{T_k}1_D(B_t)dt$ depend on where we start from in $D$?

Comment: 1) If the Brownian path starts at a point in $D$ (i.e. a point with modulus $\leq r$), then it will take a strictly positive time until the path reachs $G$ (because Brownian motion cannot jump; in particular $t \mapsto |B_t|$ is continuous a.s) 2) This follows from the rotational invariance of Brownian motion.

Comment: @saz Thanks, 1) I may be silly here but by the definition of $G:=B(0,2r)\supset D=B(0,r)$. So I was thinking $T_k=0$ and am wondering why $G$ was chosen that way. 2)

Comment: 2) If $\tau_{r}$ is the exit time of the ball, then $B_{\tau_r}$ is uniformly distributed on the boundary of the ball but in $\int_{S_k}^{T_k}1_D(B_t)dt$, since we are looking at the occupation time of $D$ between $S_k$ and $T_k$, I was thinking if we start at a point close to the boundary of $B(0,r)$, we would have lower occupation time than if we start from the origin?

Comment: 1) Sorry, I was reading what I expected to read... namely, $G=B(0,2r)^c$ (rather than $G=B(0,2r)$). You are absolutely right that $D \subseteq G$ would imply $T_k=0$.

Comment: @saz Thanks, must be a typo in Durrett then.